# How can I modify the variable result from a FOR-LOOP and output the modified variable?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables

I want to run a Windows batch FOR loop on a text file and strip spaces from the resulting variable, and then output each modified variable into text file.

I think I will need to use enabledelayedexpansion for this, but I cannot get the proper syntax

Here is an example to reproduce:

```
(
echo Here is my first line
echo Here is my second line
echo Here is my third line
)>"textfile.txt"

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('TYPE textfile.txt') DO (
    (
        ECHO @ECHO OFF
        ECHO ECHO PLEASE WAIT
        ECHO ECHO.
        ECHO "%%windir%%\system32\cscript" "%%windir%%\system32\script.vbs" -\\REMOTESERVER\%%G
    )>%%G.txt
)
```

This code works as expected and outputs 3 files:

```
Here is my first line.txt
Here is my second line.txt
Here is my third line.txt
```

Here is my first line.txt contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO PLEASE WAIT
ECHO.
"%windir%\system32\cscript" "%windir%\system32\script.vbs" \\REMOTESERVER\Here is my first line
```

Here is my second line.txt contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO PLEASE WAIT
ECHO.
"%windir%\system32\cscript" "%windir%\system32\script.vbs" \\REMOTESERVER\Here is my second line
```

and so on.

I now want to strip the spaces.  I want the files to be named:

```
Hereismyfirstline.txt
Hereismysecondline.txt
Hereismythirdline.txt
```

and I want them to contain:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO PLEASE WAIT
ECHO.
"%windir%\system32\cscript" "%windir%\system32\script.vbs" \\REMOTESERVER\Hereismyfirstline
```

and so on.

To accomplish this, I think that I need to use enabledelayedexpansion and add:

```
SET variable=%%G
SET variable=!variable: =!
```

But I am unsure how to add that to the code to the FOR loop and convert my % variables to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
echo Here is my first line
echo Here is my second line
echo Here is my third line
)>"textfile.txt"

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('TYPE textfile.txt') DO (
    set "var=%%G"
    set "var=!var: =!"
    (
        ECHO @ECHO OFF
        ECHO ECHO PLEASE WAIT
        ECHO ECHO.
        ECHO "%%windir%%\system32\cscript" "%%windir%%\system32\script.vbs" -\\REMOTESERVER\!var!
    )>!var!.txt
)
```